# Getting too many requests using Twilio Error 20429

Tags: node.js, twilio, one-time-password

I haven't upgraded my account yet, and I was wondering if the issue is regarding my free trial account or if I'm doing something wrong here.
Below you can find my logs as I didn't even reach 15 requests in 1 hour.
I'm sending the verified OTP through the free number they gave me which I think it is located in the US and I'm receiving the messages in Jordan.
Any help would be appreciated... Thank you all.     [image]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Verify has some different [rate limits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/rate-limits-and-timeouts) to the rest of the API. There is a blog post which covers [good practices for testing with Verify and how to avoid being rate limited](https://www.twilio.com/blog/test-verify-no-rate-limits) that you should read.

Comment: I have installed twilio CLI for the testing now, but my question why am I getting the error? 
Is it because I keep request otp from the same number? Or I have otp limitation because my account is free trial?

Comment: I think it’s too many requests to the same number. But as long as you correctly enter or cancel the verification you should be ok.